# Alternative for Aldryn-forms (Django-CMS)

Tags: django, django-cms, divio

Divio announced an end of support for Aldryn-forms at the end of September 2020. (http://support.divio.com/en/articles/3849075-essential-knowledge-django-addons-list).
I'm looking for add-on alternatives for Aldryn-forms that can work with the latest versions of Django, Django-CMS and Phyton.
On the marketplace website I only could find one package but its' last update was in 2015.

Does anyone knows a good package or has some information to implement forms which can be edited by content editors in the frontend website.

Thanks for any help.
Regards,
Carla

Answer (score 4):

Divio handled over the maintenance to me, since I have commercial projects running on aldryn-forms.

Also Django CMS Association is most likely going to continue at least the basic maintenance of aldryn-forms, simply because the only alternative that I know of (djangocms-forms) has been dead for ~4 years, and the end users definitely need the forms support in django CMS.

In the future I hope to release a backward incompatible rewrite of aldryn-forms, since the current version has rather frustrating UX. Yet when that happens the respective announcement is going to be published on the aldryn-forms github.

Comment: Greetings! Any news on this? Do you have a repo of the project?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem these days. I started looking online for an alternative. Without success. But a collage had found this:

https://github.com/CZ-NIC/djangocms-aldryn-forms

Looks great! It is a continuation of the old **aldryn-forms** project and seems to be well maintained.

Interesting why can't find it directly using Google Search...